# Highlight piece of codes with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, colors, code-coverage, highlight

I want to know if an Eclipse plugin exists in order to highlight some pieces of code.
We are a team that needs to upgrade an application to a new version and we have to know the code that has already been reused or considered as useless.

The aim is at the end of the upgrade to identify quickly the code which is not highlight in order to check why this code has not been reused (or considered as useless).

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code coverage tool.

http://www.eclemma.org/

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for
http://editbox.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I tried this plugin but it is based on code level. You cannot arbitrary highlight pieces of code.